# How to move files from directory /foo (1) to directory /foo

Tags: command-line, bash, filename

I know this is basic, but I'm failry new to bash.

Due to some duplication I have many photos in many folders and I'd like to clean them up. Here is an example of my file structure

```
- 12-30-14
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
- 12-30-14 (1)
  - img3.jpg
- 12-30-15
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
- 12-30-15 (1)
  - img3.jpg
```

I'd like to run a script that results in

```
- 12-30-14
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
  - img3.jpg
- 12-30-14 (1)
- 12-30-15
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
  - img3.jpg
- 12-30-15 (1)
```

From there I intend to run `find . type d -empty -delete` so that the end result is:

```
- 12-30-14
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
  - img3.jpg
- 12-30-15
  - img1.jpg
  - img2.jpg
  - img3.jpg
```

I'm just not sure the right way to move the files over from the `(1)` directory into the clean directory.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this using this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in *'(1)'*; do
    mv "$dir"/* "${dir% (1)}"
    rmdir "$dir"
done
```

Put this in a file, said `script.sh`, then in a terminal:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Comment: beware it will overwrite duplicates, I would sleep a lot better adding `-i` to mv.